# Getting data from sub-set of collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a collection called registered. Here is the code for it in the controller:

```
      @rsvped_events = @volunteer.events.includes(:event_rsvps, :rsvp_users, :shifts).current.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
```

and here is the code from the view:

```
<% unless @rsvped_events.empty? %>
<%= render :partial => "registered", :collection => @rsvped_events %>
<%= will_paginate @rsvped_events %>
```

and the partial:

```
<li><%= registered.date %></li>
<li><%= link_to registered.name, event_path(registered) %></li>
```

When a user registers for an event, it is recorded in an event_rsvps table with a myriad of info. The issue I am having is pulling out the date of the event_rsvp. I can pull out the date from the event itself, but not from the event_rsvp. These are sometimes different if the event spans multiple days and the user picks the day they want.)

I've tried the following already with varied results, but nothing works:

```
registered.date  #gives me the date of the event, but not the rsvp
registered.event_rsvp.date  #undefined method `event_rsvp' for #<Event:0x007ff7cc9d2940>
registered.event_rsvps.date  #undefined method `date' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff7d4fcea30>
```

However, if I go into Rails console, I can pull up the date by

```
u = User.find(1)
u.event_rsvps.find(90).date
```

Thoughts on how to get to that date on the event_rsvp and not on the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is association you can call it like

```
registered.event_rsvps.first.date
```

This will return you date of the first object from event_rsvps associated with the registered.

If you need to receive dates collection of all associated event_rsvps the you need to `map` them like following:

```
registered.event_rsvps.map(&:date)
```